# click on a div box with href

Tags: javascript, href

I have this code

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front" style="background: url(games/racegame/foto/fotozonder.PNG) 0 0 no-repeat;">
        </div>
        <div class="back" style="background:#00B9FF;>
            <a href="http://ispeedzone.com" rel="nofollow"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so when the mouse hoves above it it flips 180 so i see the back. But what i wanna do is
when the mouse hovers and you can see the back you can then click and in this case go to ispeedzone.com 
someone know how to do that?

Comment: So you want the code to flip it? Or is the given code not working?

Comment: no the code works and it flips good
but what i wanna do is
that when the mouse hovers over the image you see the class called back right now the background is blue. i want that back clickable so it goes to a page for this example ispeedzone.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.flip-container {
 perspective: 1000;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
 width: 320px;
 height: 480px;
}

.flipper {
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;

 position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;

 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.front {
 z-index: 2;
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
    background: orange;
}

.back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background: yellow;
}
   
.back a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper, .flip-container.flip .flipper {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
 <div class="flipper">
  <div class="front">
   hover to see back
  </div>
  <div class="back">
            <a href="http://ispeedzone.com" target="_blank">http://ispeedzone.com</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/67ad9e8h/**

Comment: hi but than i need to press the link what i wanna do is just press the back so in your case just press the yellow box and then it goes to ispeedzone

Comment: Yeah so pressing the back (yellow box) should take you to the hyperlink http://jsfiddle.net/67ad9e8h/

Comment: yeah it works now thanks
But it doesnt work with internet explorer it just shows the front and back image  as the same image but the back should be blue

Comment: @superman123 to help others, mark the answer that answered your question as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's definately easier if you provide a jsfiddle or similar. But what you could do is simply make the anchor tag span the full width by using position:relative; on its parent div, then use position:absolute; and top/right/bottom/left:0.

Alternatively if the width/height is known, just use display block on the anchor tag and set its width height to match the parent div.

I think there might be some issues in IE if the tag is empty, however you can bypass that by adding some dummy text inside the anchor tag and set its text-indent property to something crazy like -100000px to make the text non visible.

Comment: i created the code i used in jsfiddle im not familirar with that program so i just pasted it in but it doesnt owrk?
You can see it here
http://jsfiddle.net/r41fmj6n/

Comment: @superman123 why is the HTML code in the JavaScript box? FTFY http://jsfiddle.net/r41fmj6n/2/

Comment: Superman123 see @Moogs jsfiddle, you can just remove the text inside the anchor tag to make it look its not a link and it works.